# E-mail not getting sent in Joomla in combo with VM

Tags: php, email, joomla

I'm new to SO, so bear with me please. I'm fairly noobish regarding code, I'm mostly a webdesigner, not developer. But my own webdeveloper is having a hard time with this problem so I'm trying to find some help where ever I can get.
So, we got this problem on a Virtuemart shop, running version 2.5.23 of Joomla with VM 2.6.10.

Server info:

- **PHP Built On Linux web04 3.13.0-35-generic #62~precise1-Ubuntu**
- **Database Version:**  5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1-log
- **Database Collation:** utf8_general_ci
- **PHP Version:** 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14
- **Web Server:** Apache
- **WebServer to PHP Interface:** apache2handler
- **Joomla! Version:** Joomla! 2.5.23 Stable [ Ember ] 24-July-2014 14:00 GMT

So this is not sending mail anywhere. We got it on a testserver and over there, life is good. It's sending e-mail. The testserver is running PHP 5.24.

I've used this to see if this checks out:

```
<?php

$to = "dontsentmemail@gmail.com";
if( mail( $to , 'This is a test message.' , 'Is this working?' ) ) {
    echo 'Email sent.';
} else {
    echo 'Email failed to send.';
}

?>
```

This is working fine. And I'm about to pull out all my hair. We've tried SMTP mail handling, and again, working like a charm on the testserver but it won't work on the live site.

does anybody know if is VM/joomla is using mail() directly or maybe using JUtility::sendMail() as default, and if we can change that, to make it work? Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Also checked to see the server is not blacklisted, that's all okay..

Comment: mail() is returning false? then php is misconfigured or you don't have an SMTP server installed. It's returning true? Then check the smtp server's logs to see what happens after PHP handed over the email.

Comment: Why dont you use Joomla's built in `JMail` class?

Comment: Can I edit this code to see if the JMail resolves it?

Comment: @Kimberly - see my answer for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I wasn't aware Joomla already includes its own version of PHPMailer. See Lodder's answer for a better out-of-the-box solution!

---

Try switching to a specialist mail library, e.g. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send the mail, instead of php's mail function.

I too had a similar problem, emails sent but not delivered, and no bounce messages. PHPMailer managed to send email that also got delivered.

```
<?php
require_once('path/to/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
$mail->isSendmail();

// Set who the message is to be sent from
// Name is optional
$mail->setFrom('somebody@yourdomain.com', 'Joe Bloggs');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
// Name is optional
$mail->addAddress('dontsentmemail@gmail.com', 'Jane Bliggs');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Is this working?';

// Set plain text body
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Body = 'This is a test message.';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: No point in manually importing PHPMailer when Joomla has it's own built-in method for this ;)

Comment: Not familiar with Joomla. Sounds like the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use Joomla's built-in `JMail` class which uses **PHPMailer**. Have a look at the following:

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

$mailer->setSender('dontsentmemail@gmail.com');
$mailer->addRecipient('from@emailaddress.com');
$mailer->setSubject('Your subject');

$body = "Some email text";
$mailer->setBody($body);

$send = $mailer->Send();
if ( $send !== true ) 
{
    echo 'Error sending email';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Mail sent';
}
```

You may want to change `from@emailaddress.com` to whatever suits your needs. There are also some additional features for this class which can be found on the Joomla documentation:

http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

### Update:

I wasn't aware that you were using a separate PHP file. At the top of your PHP file, you will need to import the Joomla framework like so:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

You may need to change the value for `JPATH_BASE` so that your script points to the root of your Joomla site, relative to where you PHP file is located.

Hope this helps

Comment: When I used your code in a php-file to test it out, I get a blank screen. i placed it in the rootdirectory of the website, maybe that's the problem? I don't even get the 'error sending email' echo.

Comment: @Kimberly - You can't simply use Joomla code in a separate PHP file. If you wish to do this, you you need to import the Joomla framework. See my updated answer

Comment: if you are using a php file outside of the joomla framework, you need to load the joomla framework into that file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937651/load-joomla-3-x-framework-and-modules-in-external-php-file

Comment: Hey Lodder, didn't know that, oops! Trying now!

Comment: It's getting a little over my head now, I uploaded the script as you told me to, with the joomla framework imported in the rootmap. From root, it's the same JPATH_BASE as in the example, right?

Comment: The current definition for `JPATH_BASE` is `../`, so this is the value that will possibly need to be changed. If you provided your file structure in your question, I would be able to give you a more accurate answer ;)

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry :)
I'm in /domains/mydomain.nl/htdocs/shop/
There's the testfile. Total Joomla root.
Is that what you needed to know?

Comment: So the PHP file is in the root of your Joomla installation (same directory as *configuration.php*) ?

Comment: This should work then: `define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);`

Comment: I've created the file like you told, and it says 'Mail sent' but I'm not receiving. Is this helpfull to see where the problem is at?

Comment: If you're not receiving the mail then it will be a server related issue or a problem with your email client. Make sure you check the spam folder for your email account

Comment: We interchanged the entire mail-code with Core PHP mail, and now it's working. What a work ;)