# How to get correct URL in Joomla from external code?

Tags: php, joomla, url-routing

I'm accessing the Joomla framework from some external code as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937818/37947). The website is at `http://localhost/joomla/` and the external code is in `http://localhost/joomla/external/index.php`

I have `JPATH_BASE` set properly to the Joomla root, and generate a URL like this:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login')
```

But that comes back with the URL `/joomla/external/index.php/login` instead of what it should be: `/joomla/index.php/login`

How to fix this?

Edit: to make clear, I'm looking for a general solution for any folder structure. The external folder could be in another location e.g. `http://localhost/external/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out a solution - I needed to set the site's base URL in the `configuration.php` file:

```
public $live_site = 'http://localhost/joomla/';
```

Now calling `JRoute::_` returns the correct paths, wherever the external code is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, trim the trailing string from the end of the base URL and use that in `JRoute`, like so:

```
$base = rtrim(JUri::base(), JUri::base(true));

JRoute::_($base . '/index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
```

---

#### Testing for visual purposes:

```
$base     = JUri::base();
$baseTrue = JUri::base(true);
$baseRoot = rtrim($base, $baseTrue);

var_dump($base);
var_dump($baseTrue);
var_dump($baseRoot);
var_dump(JRoute::_($baseRoot . '/index.php?option=com_users&view=login'));
```

**Output:**

```
> 'http://example.loc/media/'                                (length=24)
> '/media'                                                   (length=6)
> 'http://example.loc'                                       (length=17)
> 'http://example.loc/index.php?option=com_users&view=login' (length=55)
```

*Note: `/media` is just the directory I put my standalone PHP file in*

Comment: This doesn't work - I get `http://localhost/index.php...` when it should be `http://localhost/joomla/index.php...` BTW I should add that I'm looking for something that works in any circumstance like if the `external/` directory is in a completely different location.